# Add Line Break/Remove Commas for Checkbox options sent via Email from Contact Form 7

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

Currently when someone submits a contact form that contains multiple checkbox options, when it comes through via email it’s all on the same line split by commas.

Is it possible to change the Contact Form 7 email format so it instead adds a line break and removes the commas for checkbox options? We do want it to remain as it is on the actual contact form (where the options are all in one line/a paragraph, not split up by line breaks) – just want the email results to change.

**So for example we would like to checkbox results sent via email to showing:**
Eggs, Bread, Milk, Water, Oranges

**To this (without the bulletpoint):**

- Eggs
- Bread
- Milk
- Water
- Oranges

Is this possible? And if so how would we configure this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, this is possible using the CF7 `'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced'` filter,

```
add_filter('wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced', 'format_chackbox',10,4);
function format_chackbox($replaced, $submitted, $is_html, $mail_tag){
  //you can check if this is the right field if need be.
  if('my-checkbox-field' != $mail_tag->field_name()) return $replaced;
  //$submitted contains the raw submitted data.
  //$replaced is the formatted data, you can use either.
  $a = explode(',', $replaced);
  //check if you have multiple values and the email accepts html (set with the use html checkbox in the mail notification settings).
  if(is_array($a) && $is_html){
    $replaced = '<ul>'.PHP_EOL;
    foreach($a as $v) $replaced .= '<li>'.trim($v).'</li>'.PHP_EOL;
    $replaced .= '</ul>'.PHP_EOL;
  }
  return $replaced;
}
```

place this in your `functions.php` file

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry I'm not too sure where I would add this code? I've tried adding ti to the "functions.php" file in my child theme and the "wp-contact-form-7.php" file in the CF7 plugin folder? - but both return a your website is in critical condition when I go to it on WordPress.

Comment: ah yes, I realise I forgot a `;` after the first line.  Copy paste the corrected code into your functions.php file

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you so much for your help!